# "can we get out for a moment to check for our car?"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

My friend and I went to a theme park. Our car parked outside of the park. To enter the theme park the staff needed to scan our tickets. But once we entered, we realized we didn’t pay for the parking so we need to get back to the parking lot, which is outside of the theme park and we needed to pass through the staff who scanned our tickets and told them that we wanted to check something briefly and will come back soon so they could let us in. I wonder how I should express this.

What I said was:

> can we get out for a moment to check for our car?

I guess it sounds awkward but the staff figured out what I meant. But I was wondering what some of the more natural and accurate ways of express this are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you had a successful communication.  It is normal that people engage in a dialogue to establish understanding. In fact it is unusual to give a "speech" to which the other person listens and then understands.

So rather than ask "what should we have said", expect to speak, allow the other person to respond and ask questions, listen to their questions, and respond back...

As mentioned in comments, think what do you really want to know and what information do you really want to give.  You want to know if you can get back in without paying.  You want to tell them that you need to go and pay for parking.

> Excuse me, I think I forgot to pay for parking. Can I quickly go and pay.
>
> {response}
>
> {respond back} ... Will I be able to get back in without having to pay again?
>
> {response}
>
> {respond back} etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit awkward: "check for our car" sounds as though you were not certain where it was parked. "Check on our car" sounds as though you were concerned about the current condition of your car. What you meant was "pay for our car."

But people often misspeak, and so people listening make corrections. Not to worry

Comment: Thanks but I am more concerned with the usage of "can we get out for a moment". How would you describe the intention of leaving the park for a brief time and will come back soon?

Comment: Again, it almost certainly will be understood, but it is not exactly what you mean. "If we leave for a few minutes to pay for our car, can we get back in without having to repay?" Of course you can leave for a moment or for eternity, but the real question is whether you can get back in without paying a second time. Best to say exactly what you mean.